# Android studio sqlite and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I wanted to develop a simple program with fragments and sqlite. In fact i could write sqlite program before. I followed this project 
https://github.com/mitchtabian/SQLiteSaveUserData 
i wrote db that can add, update, delete. 
Now i want to write a program that has 3 fragments. one of them is add fragment. But when i run program, program give error. "Keeps stopping Close App"

DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "people.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
public static final String COL1 = "ID";
public static final String COL2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL3 = "EMAIL";
public static final String COL4 = "TVSHOW";



public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " NAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, TVSHOW TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String name, String email, String tvShow){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL3,email);
    contentValues.put(COL4, tvShow);

    long result  = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor showData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}

public boolean updateData(String id, String name, String email, String tvShow){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL1,id);
    contentValues.put(COL2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL3,email);
    contentValues.put(COL4,tvShow);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteData(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mTextMessage;
Fragment fragmentTemp = null;
FrameLayout fmalan;

Button btnAdd;
EditText etEng,etTr,etCom;

public DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                mTextMessage.setText("Ekle");
                fragmentTemp = new Fragment_Add();
                Fragment_Add_Func(fragmentTemp);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                mTextMessage.setText("Test");
                fragmentTemp = new Fragment_test();
                Fragment_Add_Func(fragmentTemp);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                mTextMessage.setText("Listele");
                fragmentTemp = new Fragment_List();
                Fragment_Add_Func(fragmentTemp);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};








protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);


    fmalan = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.alan);
    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PageShow);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    etEng=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etdEng);
    etTr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etdTr);
    etCom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etdComment);

      AddData();

}

public void AddData(){

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String Eng=etEng.getText().toString();
            String Tr=etTr.getText().toString();
            String Com=etCom.getText().toString();

            boolean insertData = dbhelper.addData(Eng, Tr, Com);
            if (insertData == true) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Successfully Inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong :(.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


    });
}




public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);
    return true;
}




public void Fragment_Add_Func(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fmalan != null) {
        fmalan.removeAllViews();
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.alan, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

}

FragmentAdd

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Fragment_Add extends Fragment {

DatabaseHelper dbhelper;

public Fragment_Add() {



}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__add, container, false);
}



}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: logcat please post.

Comment: Share the stack trace please